# How to update contents of a subtable in a larger table in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large table with 70,000 rows with the following structure:

```
Sno.   Email .       Status
1 .    email id 1 .  Active
2 .    email id 2 .  Inactive
...
70000. email id 70k  Active
```

Now I have a smaller table, with the same structure but 20 rows and new status for 20 of these 70,000 email ids. I want to update the information in the respective columns of the main table.

How can I do that using pandas?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: something `merge` on `Email` would work

Comment: or [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First: **rename** `status_col` of `small_df`
- Then **merge** both `df` on `email id`
- **Replace** original status with `new_status`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

small_df.rename(columns={'status':'new_status'},inplace=True)

final_df = pd.merge(large_df,small_df,on=['email_id],how='left)
final_df['status']=np.where(final_df['new_status'].notnull(),
                            final_df['new_status'],final_df['status'])

del df['new_status']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a pandas DataFrame structure like

```
    x    y
A  val  val
B  val  val
C  val  val
```

you can use the command `.at` or `.iat` to edit or add value to a cell:

```
df.at['C', 'x'] = 10
```